# What's the difference between http request and writing http request text to tcp/ip socket on 80 port

Tags: http, sockets

Can someone explain the difference between the HTTP request and it handling and socket requests on 80 port. As I understood, HTTP server listen the 80 port and when someone sends an HTTP request on this port - server handle it. So when we place socket listener on port 80, and then write HTML formatted message to it - does it means that we send usual HTTP request? But as fiddler said - it false. What's the difference on a packet level? Or another *lower than presentation*-level between HTTP request and HTTP-formed writing to socket? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, port 80 is the default port for HTTP, it is not required. You can have HTTP servers listening on other ports as well.

Regarding the difference between "regular" HTTP requests and the ones you make yourself over a  socket - there is no difference. The "regular" HTTP requests you are referring to (made by a web browser for example) are also implemented over sockets, just like you would do it manually yourself. And the same goes for the server. The implementation of the HTTP server listens for incoming socket connections and parses the data that passes there just like you would.

As long as you send in your socket valid HTTP protocol (according to the RFC), there should be no difference in the packet level (if the lower network stack is identical).

Keep in mind that the socket layer is just the layer the HTTP data always passes over. It doesn't really matter who put the data there, it just comes out from the other side the same way it was put in.

Please note that you have some degree of freedom when implementing an HTTP yourself. There are many optional fields and the order of the headers doesn't matter. So it is possible that two different HTTP implementations will be different in the packet level, but will behave basically the same.

The best way to actually see what's going on in the packet level, is by using a network sniffer - like wireshark or packetyzer. A sniffer actually records the packets of the network and shows you their content. So if you record several HTTP implementations (from various browsers) and your own socket implementation, you can make the required changes to make them identical in the packet level.

Comment: Thank for response and for pointing on tools, going to try them. You said what i mean before - that well-formed write in socket is http. I don't write my own server=) I just working with some api that provided via sockets on 80 port, and write text to socket in a response on a http-formed request. I make it with c# TcpClient object. But just i start to work througt wrapped and beautified HttpWebRequest object - returns an error. And moreover - writings with TcpClient isn't tracked by fiddler, that track all http requests. So one more time thanks for tools will try them.

Comment: yeah.. well formed writing you do in the socket is perfect HTTP

Comment: i have some editings in prev post, don't familiar with stackowerflow yet

Comment: Got it! Wireshurk rules! Guys who wrote a soap service inserts a dummy symbols before message. The worst soap in my life.